# Android MediaPlayer Checking instances

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-mediaplayer

I am having my layout xml file displays like below:

```
Song1    playbutton
Song2    playbutton
Song3     playbutton
```

when ever user clicks on Song1 playbutton i need to play Song1 ,In the middle if user clicks on Song2 playbutton there  i need to check for Song2 and Song3 mediapalyer instances

I'm getting IllegalStateException and some times NullPointerException
How to Check, Could any one help?

Here my Code:

```
MediaPlayer mp1=new MediaPlayer();
MediaPlayer mp2=new MediaPlayer();

playbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mp2!=null){
                if(mp2.isPlaying()){
                    mp2.stop();
                    mp2.release();
                    mp2=null;

                    play20.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);




                }
                }
                playbtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                pausebtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                try {

                    Log.d("Start Media Player", "Start Media Player");
                    AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = MediaActivity.this
                            .getApplicationContext().getAssets()
                            .openFd("volumc.mp3");
                    mp1.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(),
                            descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength());
                    // descriptor.close();
                    mp1.prepare();
                    mp1.setLooping(true);
                    mp1.start();


                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        pausebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.d("pausebtn", "pausebtn");
                playbtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                pausebtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                mp1.stop();
                mp1.release();
                mp1=null;


            }
        });

        // 20

        play20.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(mp1!=null){
                if(mp1.isPlaying()){
                    mp1.stop();
                    mp1.release();
                    mp1=null;
                    playbtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);



                }
                }
                play20.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                pause20.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                try {

                    Log.d("Start Media Player", "Start Media Player");
                    AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = MediaActivity.this
                            .getApplicationContext().getAssets()
                            .openFd("volumc.mp3");
                    mp2.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(),
                            descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength());
                    // descriptor.close();
                    mp2.prepare();
                    mp2.setLooping(true);
                    mp2.start();

                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        pause20.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Log.d("pausebtn", "pausebtn");
                play20.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                pause20.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                mp2.stop();
                mp2.release();


            }
        });
```

Comment: Please take a look at the answer and mark it as accepted if it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use one Mediaplayer instance per button. Creating many instances will not benefit. Instead create only one mediaplayer instance and check if the music is playing. 
you can always make a method to stop playing media player like

```
private void stopAndStartMediaPlayer(String datasource)
{
    if(mp.isPlaying())
        mp.stop();
    mp.reset();
    mp.setDataSource(datasource);
    mp.prepare();
    mp.start();
}
```

Comment: You should add a call to `reset()` before `setDataSource(...)`, and a call to `prepare()` before `start()`. There's also the problem that `isPlaying()` returns false while paused, but maybe he isn't using `pause()` in this application.

Comment: @Dave I was just suggesting user2580568 that he should do a method like this. This is not the exact code but he can do something like this. So **Read carefully before you DOWNVOTE.** I have already mentioned that he can do something **"like"** right above the code.